# Cannot communicate with Serial Monitor - Arduino Yun

Tags: serial, arduino-yun

I connect Arduino Yun to my Computer with WiFi. I was able to get the IP address of my Arduino Yun. However, when I try to print something. It seems to not work at all. The following code is the one that I try:

```cpp
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);       
}

void loop() {  
 // print labels 
 Serial.print("NO FORMAT");  
 delay(100);
}
```

I did not get any kind of error. However, when I open the Serial Monitor, it shows nothing at all. I try to use the same code with Arduino Uno. It works fine.

Comment: double check the port, also check in `Device Manager` if there is the `Yun` in `Ports`. It might be the missing driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the Yun over wifi, you cannot user Serial, you need to use Bridge [Console](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunConsoleConstructor) object. Serial is bound to the usb cable.

Give a spin to [ConsoleRead](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConsoleRead) example.

Comment: Moreover, can you take a look at my other question with Arduino Yun?http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/grove-temperature-with-arduino-yun