# Grove temperature sensor with Arduino Yun

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-yun, temperature-sensor

I try to test Grove - Infrared Temperature Sensor on Arduino Yun with the sample code but it does not work. In the console it shows that the object temperature is out of range all the time. However, when I try to test it on Arduino Uno, it works fine.

My sketch:

```
#include <math.h>
#include<Console.h>
//#include <NewSoftSerial.h>       //if display in LCD(seeed serial LCD driver)
//#include <SerialLCD.h>           //if display in LCD(seeed serial LCD driver)
//#include "temp.h"

const int temp_analog_in = A0;  // Analog input pin connect to temperature sensor SUR pin
const int objt_analog_in = A1;  // Analog input pin connect to temperature sensor OBJ pin
float temp_calibration = 0;     //this parameter was used to calibrate the temperature
//float objt_calibration=0.000; //this parameter was used to calibrate the object temperature
float temperature_range = 10;  //we make a map of temperature-voltage according to sensor datasheet. 10 is the temperature step when sensor and
//object distance is 9CM.
float offset_vol = 0.014;      //this parameter was used to set the mid level voltage,when put the sensor in normal environment after 10 min,
//the sensor output 0.For example,the surrounding temperature is 29℃，but the result is 27℃ via the sensor,
//you should set the reerence to 0.520 or more,according to your sensor to change.
//the unit is V

//SerialLCD slcd(11,12);
float tempValue = 0;
float objtValue = 0;
float current_temp = 0;
float temp = 0;
float temp1 = 0;
float temp2 = 0;
unsigned int temp3 = 0;
const float reference_vol = 0.500;
unsigned char clear_num = 0; //when use lcd to display
float R = 0;
float voltage = 0;


long res[100] = {
  318300, 302903, 288329, 274533, 261471, 249100, 237381, 226276, 215750, 205768,
  196300, 187316, 178788, 170691, 163002, 155700, 148766, 142183, 135936, 130012,
  124400, 119038, 113928, 109059, 104420, 100000, 95788, 91775, 87950, 84305,
  80830, 77517, 74357, 71342, 68466, 65720, 63098, 60595, 58202, 55916,
  53730, 51645, 49652, 47746, 45924, 44180, 42511, 40912, 39380, 37910,
  36500, 35155, 33866, 32631, 31446, 30311, 29222, 28177, 27175, 26213,
  25290, 24403, 23554, 22738, 21955, 21202, 20479, 19783, 19115, 18472,
  17260, 16688, 16138, 15608, 15098, 14608, 14135, 13680, 13242, 12819,
  12412, 12020, 11642, 11278, 10926, 10587, 10260, 9945, 9641, 9347,
  9063, 8789, 8525, 8270, 8023, 7785, 7555, 7333, 7118, 6911
};

float obj [13][12] = {
  /*0*/             { 0, -0.274, -0.58, -0.922, -1.301, -1.721, -2.183, -2.691, -3.247, -3.854, -4.516, -5.236}, //
  /*1*/             { 0.271, 0, -0.303, -0.642, -1.018, -1.434, -1.894, -2.398, -2.951, -3.556, -4.215, -4.931}, //→surrounding temperature,from -10,0,10,...100
  /*2*/             { 0.567, 0.3, 0, -0.335, -0.708, -1.121, -1.577, -2.078, -2.628, -3.229, -3.884, -4.597}, //↓object temperature,from -10,0,10,...110
  /*3*/             { 0.891, 0.628, 0.331, 0, -0.369, -0.778, -1.23, -1.728, -2.274, -2.871, -3.523, -4.232},
  /*4*/             { 1.244, 0.985, 0.692, 0.365, 0, -0.405, -0.853, -1.347, -1.889, -2.482, -3.13, -3.835},
  /*5*/             { 1.628, 1.372, 1.084, 0.761, 0.401, 0, -0.444, -0.933, -1.47, -2.059, -2.702, -3.403},
  /*6*/             { 2.043, 1.792, 1.509, 1.191, 0.835, 0.439, 0, -0.484, -1.017, -1.601, -2.24, -2.936},
  /*7*/             { 2.491, 2.246, 1.968, 1.655, 1.304, 0.913, 0.479, 0, -0.528, -1.107, -1.74, -2.431},
  /*8*/             { 2.975, 2.735, 2.462, 2.155, 1.809, 1.424, 0.996, 0.522, 0, -0.573, -1.201, -1.887},
  /*9*/             { 3.495, 3.261, 2.994, 2.692, 2.353, 1.974, 1.552, 1.084, 0.568, 0, -0.622, -1.301},
  /*10*/            { 4.053, 3.825, 3.565, 3.27, 2.937, 2.564, 2.148, 1.687, 1.177, 0.616, 0, -0.673},
  /*11*/            { 4.651, 4.43, 4.177, 3.888, 3.562, 3.196, 2.787, 2.332, 1.829, 1.275, 0.666, 0},
  /*12*/            { 5.29, 5.076, 4.83, 4.549, 4.231, 3.872, 3.47, 3.023, 2.527, 1.98, 1.379, 0.72}
};

float binsearch(long x)// this function used for measure the surrounding temperature
{
  int low, mid, high;
  low = 0;
  //mid=0;
  high = 100;
  while (low <= high)
  {
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (x < res[mid])
      low = mid + 1;
    else//(x>res[mid])
      high = mid - 1;
  }
  return mid;
}

float arraysearch(float x, float y) //x is the surrounding temperature,y is the object temperature
{
  int i = 0;
  float tem_coefficient = 100;
  i = (x / 10) + 1;
  voltage = (float)y / tem_coefficient;
  //Serial.print("sensor voltage:\t");
  //Serial.print(voltage,5);
  //Serial.print("V");
  for (temp3 = 0; temp3 < 13; temp3++)
  {
    if ((voltage > obj[temp3][i]) && (voltage < obj[temp3 + 1][i]))
    {
      return temp3;
    }
  }
}

float temp_measure()
{
  unsigned char i = 0;
  float current_temp1 = 0;
  int signal = 0;
  tempValue = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //
  {
    tempValue += analogRead(temp_analog_in);
    delay(10);
  }
  tempValue = tempValue / 10;
  temp = tempValue * 1.1 / 1023;
  R = 2000000 * temp / (2.50 - temp);
  signal = binsearch(R);
  current_temp = signal - 1 + temp_calibration + (res[signal - 1] - R) / (res[signal - 1] - res[signal]);
  //current_temp1=current_temp;
  //slcd.setCursor(0,1);
  //slcd.print("sur T:");
  //slcd.print((int)current_temp1,DEC);
  Console.print("Surrounding temperature:");
  Console.print(current_temp);
  return current_temp;
}

float objt_measure()
{
  unsigned char i = 0;
  unsigned char j = 0;
  float sur_temp = 0;
  unsigned int array_temp = 0;
  float temp1, temp2;
  float final_temp = 0;
  objtValue = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    objtValue += analogRead(objt_analog_in);
    delay(10);
  }
  objtValue = objtValue / 10;
  temp1 = objtValue * 1.1 / 1023; //+objt_calibration;
  sur_temp = temp1 - (reference_vol + offset_vol);
  Console.print("\t Sensor voltage:");
  Console.print(sur_temp, 3);
  Console.print("V");
  //slcd.setCursor(11,1);
  //slcd.print((int)(temp1*10000),DEC);
  array_temp = arraysearch(current_temp, sur_temp * 1000);
  temp2 = current_temp;
  temp1 = (temperature_range * voltage) / (obj[array_temp + 1][(int)(temp2 / 10) + 1] - obj[array_temp][(int)(temp2 / 10) + 1]);
  final_temp = temp2 + temp1;
  if ((final_temp > 100) || (final_temp <= -10))
  {
    Console.println ("\t out of range!");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.print("\t object temperature:");
    Console.println(final_temp, 2);
    //Serial.println("℃");
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //The fllowing code is used for display by serialLCD
  /*
    slcd.setCursor(0,0);
    slcd.print("obj T:");
    if((final_temp>=0)&&(final_temp<=100))
    {
      slcd.print(final_temp,DEC);
    }
    else if((final_temp<0)&&(final_temp>=-10))
    {
      slcd.setCursor(10,0);
      slcd.print('-');
      slcd.print(abs(final_temp),DEC);
    }
    else
      {
        slcd.setCursor(5,0);
        slcd.print("out of range");
        }*/
  //////////////////////////////////////////
}

void setup()
{
  Bridge.begin();
  Console.begin();
  while (!Console);
  Console.println("Hi, what's your name?");// initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  //slcd.begin();//Add while using LCD to display
  //slcd.backlight();//Turn on the backlight of LCD while using LCD to display
  analogReference(INTERNAL);//set the refenrence voltage 1.1V,the distinguishability can up to 1mV.
  //analogReference(INTERNAL1V1);//(mega only)set the refenrence voltage 1.1V,the distinguishability can up to 1mV.
}
//If use LCD to display, adding below code to clear the screen in time
void loop()
{
  temp_measure();
  objt_measure();

  /*
    if(clear_num==10)
      {
        slcd.clear();
        clear_num=0;
        }
    else
      clear_num++;
  */
}
```

I am sure that I connected the wires properly. The exact same wiring configuration is used with Arduino Uno.

Comment: What's the current output?

Comment: The current out put is 5V.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "what does the sketch print right now?"